# angular validate multiple choices in reactive form

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-ngmodel

I'm new to angular, I'm facing a problem with validation of the gender of the user
by default the gender is not set, and the form is for update user data, maybe the user will set his gender and back again to update something else, now the user gender has been set so wanted to make it selected according to user data
so here in my case data.general.gender is Male
but nothing selected both are not selected

**HTML**

```
this.instructorGeneralForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  gender: ['', [Validators.required]]
```

**Code**

```
<div class="demo-inline-spacing">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" 
      id="gender_male" 
      name="gender"
      formControlName="gender"
      class="custom-control-input" 
      [checked]="data.general.gender === 'Male'" [value]="'Male'"
      />
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="gender_male">I'm Male</label>
   </div>
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" 
      id="gender_female" 
      name="gender"
      formControlName="gender"
      class="custom-control-input" 
      value="Female"
      [checked]="data.general.gender === 'Female'" [value]="'Female'"
      />
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="gender_female">I'm Female</label>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="submitted && generalForm.gender.errors" class="invalid-feedback"
   [ngClass]="{ 'd-block': submitted && generalForm.gender.errors }">
     <div *ngIf="generalForm.gender.errors.required">Gender is required</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `checked` attribute conditionally would only reflect the `checked` state of radio box. This change in the state of `radio` won't reflect back in `gender` formControl.

To fix the problem, you set patchValue of form

```
this.instructorGeneralForm.patchValue({
  gender: data.general.gender,
})
```

And remove the `[checked]` attribute binding from the input radio box.

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3onh9t?)